# Differential equation with delay

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Good evening. I have the following question about the equation with delay:
How could be a correct statement for well-posedness for dalay model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your equation is
$$ \dfrac{dy}{dt} = f(t, y(t- \tau))$$
where $\tau > 0$.
The initial condition must tell you $y(t)$ for $-\tau \le t \le 0$, which should be
a continuous function.  For $0 < t \le \tau$ you get $y(t)$ by integration; the result is well-defined and depends continuously on the initial condition (let's say using the supremum norm).  Then repeat for the next interval $\tau < 0 \le 2 \tau$...

Comment: Yes. thank you very much!! I know, that $f$ is Lipschitz, $\tau$ non negative and the function that give me the initial condition is also lipschitz, so i have existence and unicity of the solution. But how I can show that depend continuosly from the initial condition? What is the definition of continue dependency of initial condition?? Thanks

Comment: If $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two solutions, for $0 < t \le \tau$ we have 
$$ |y_1(t) - y_2(t)| \le |y_1(0) - y_2(0)| +  \int_0^t |f(s,y_1(s-\tau)) - f(s, y_2(s-\tau))|\; ds \le |y_1(0) - y_2(0)| + K t \max_{-\tau \le s \le 0} |y_1(s) - y_2(s)|$$
where $K$ is the Lipschitz constant of $f$.

Comment: Thank you very much Robert!!